# Visual Studio 2022 Vue Project Layout

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, vue.js

New to Vue and SPA.

I created an out-of-the-box Vue and ASP.NET Core (Preview) project with Javascript option.

Why does the header and body of the App.vue appear side by side?  Where/how do you change this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue.

Specifically, the display: grid setting below in my main.css

```
#app {
    /*display: grid;*/ 
    grid-template-columns: 1.75fr .25fr;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}
```